# Theme hook suggestion not working

Tags: theming, nodes, 8

I've a node, I'm trying to theme the same with the title of the node. I've written the code for it. Now when looking the source code, the twig file is showing also, but it is directly taking node twig.

The suggestion is

```
$suggestions[] = 'node__' . $title;
```

The suggestion when I debug is getting the value as

node--this--is--test.html.twig

I've tried single space also,

node--this-is-test.html.twig

It is also not working.

Comment: Why you need that? One node has unique node id. You can use node--nid.html.twig for that. And more suggestions is right when title of node like **this_is_test**.

Comment: Try checking with some other field value like nid or any field which don't have spaces. You may need to convert all spaces in `$title` to underscore.

Comment: Did you clear the cache after adding the twig template? Did you enable twig debugging to see what the suggestions are in the source code?